# 「セイン星矢」 v.s. 「セイント星矢」 in the opening song of 「聖闘士星矢」

Tags: pronunciation

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RTa0ENwF2bo&feature=youtu.be&t=48s

It seems that the singer is singing 「セイン星矢」 despite the fact that the subtitle says 「セイント星矢」.

Questions:

1. Is it a phenomenon similar to [glottalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glottalization) in some dialects of English?
2. Is it productive or just a stand-alone case?

Comment: センシーヤッ！ http://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/%E3%83%9A%E3%82%AC%E3%82%B5%E3%82%B9%E5%B9%BB%E6%83%B3

Comment: @broccoliforest 星矢呀！https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XAHWHEsXh5Y

Comment: I just think they're just using a more English pronunciation of Saint. It would kinda be weird for it to be Sainto Seiya :P

Comment: It's probably as Doge says. セイント　would be the "Japanese" pronounciation, but the singer opts for the English pronounciation, and mutes the t at the end.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that the singer pronounces the english word "saint" instead of the katakana version 「セイント」. It makes sense, since 「セイント」 comes from "saint".

As for the questions:

1. The pronunciation is more of a "style" choice rather than a linguistic issue.
2. Wouldn't consider it either one, but like I said, just a stylistic phenomenon.

Comment: やれやれ、頭硬かった Orz ..